# How to get users circle details from google circle API in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using google circle API. but i am not able to find how to get  users circle details from it in android.

Comment: What "google circle API" are you using?

Comment: thanks for reply, i am using google circle API V1.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people).

Use the Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible method to make an asynchronous request to get a list of people who this user has added to one or more circles. The loadVisible method returns a list of people that are visible to the requesting app, which is the people who are in circles that the user has permitted the app to see.